# How to expand group rows by default with Vuetify 3?

Tags: vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

I need the groups in my table below to be open by default `isGroupOpen=true`:

```
  <v-data-table
    v-if="report"
    :items="report"
    :headers="headers"
    :group-by="groupBy"
    :items-per-page="itemsPerPage"
    density="compact"
  >
    <template #group-header="{ item, columns, toggleGroup, isGroupOpen }">
      <tr>
        <td :colspan="columns.length">
          Hello
        </td>
      </tr>
    </template>
  </v-data-table>
```

Where can I set it ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your data structure is but here is an example that can be tried.

Add the `isGroupOpen` property as `true` for each group like this-

```
report: [{
      group: 'Group A',
      data: [
        // YOUR DATA
      ],
      isGroupOpen: true, // set to true to open the group by default
    },
    {
      group: 'Group B',
      data: [
        // YOUR DATA
      ],
      isGroupOpen: true, // set to true to open the group by default
    },
  ],
```

And at the template side you can add icon manually to toggle the groups, like this-

```
<template #group-header="{ item, columns, toggleGroup, isGroupOpen }">
  <td :colspan="columns.length">
    Hello
    <v-icon @click="toggleGroup">
      {{ isGroupOpen ? 'mdi-chevron-up' : 'mdi-chevron-down' }}
    </v-icon>
  </td>
</template>
```